# Unable to put href links to expand results in xml using xslt file

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I designed a xslt file for a list view of house names from xml. And when a house name is clicked from the list, it should show full detail of the house which is in same xml file. But in my case it's redirecting to another place. Can someone help me?

```
<Houses>
    <search>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>horror</name>
        <address>09, west Road</address>
        <city>London</city>
        <pcode>se4 7jk</pcode>
        <contact>020574110832</contact>
        </search>
</Houses>
```

And the problem part of xslt file

```
<xsl:template match="name">
     <xsl:attribute name="href">
     <xsl:value-of select="//search/name"/>
     </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Consider to explain your requirements by posting the HTML or XML or plain text output you want to create for your posted sample XML input, then we can help with an XSLT way to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you wish to add a link to each name. In that case you will need something like

```
<xsl:template match="name">
    <a>
        <xsl:attribute name="href">
            <xsl:text>#</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </a>
</xsl:template>
```

This will create elements like `<a href="#horror">horror</a>`

**EDIT**

OK here's an example of a table with div elements that collapse/expand by clicking the button. Nice layout I left to do for you; it's just meant as an example of how to create an html using xslt including javascript toggle hide/show.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>trial</title>
                <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                    //expand and collapse functions based on id
                    function toggleById(IdStart) {
                    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
                    for (var i=0<xsl:text>;</xsl:text> i&lt;divs.length<xsl:text>;</xsl:text> i++) {
                    if (divs[i].id.match("^"+IdStart) == IdStart) { 
                        if( divs[i].style.display == "none")
                            {
                            divs[i].style.display = "block"
                            }
                        else    {
                            divs[i].style.display = "none"
                            }
                    }
                    }
                    return true;
                    }

                </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <table border="solid black 1pt;" style="border-collapse:collapse;padding:0;border-spacing:0">
                    <tr>
                        <th>house name</th>
                        <th>details</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="name">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input>
                    <xsl:attribute name="type">button</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="onclick">toggleById('<xsl:value-of select="."/>'); return true;</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="onMouseOver">this.style.cursor='hand'</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
                </input>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="style">display:none</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:copy-of select=".."/>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Houses>
    <search>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>horror</name>
        <address>09, west Road</address>
        <city>London</city>
        <pcode>se4 7jk</pcode>
        <contact>020574110832</contact>
    </search>
    <search>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>nice</name>
        <address>05, East Road</address>
        <city>London</city>
        <pcode>po4 3df</pcode>
        <contact>none</contact>
    </search>
</Houses>
```

This gives

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>trial</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                    //expand and collapse functions based on id
                    function toggleById(IdStart) {
                    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
                    for (var i=0; i<divs.length; i++) {
                    if (divs[i].id.match("^"+IdStart) == IdStart) { 
                        if( divs[i].style.display == "none")
                            {
                            divs[i].style.display = "block"
                            }
                        else    {
                            divs[i].style.display = "none"
                            }
                    }
                    }
                    return true;
                    }

                </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="solid black 1pt;" style="border-collapse:collapse;padding:0;border-spacing:0">
            <tr>
                <th>house name</th>
                <th>details</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" onclick="toggleById('horror'); return true;" onMouseOver="this.style.cursor='hand'" value="horror"></td>
                <td>
                    <div id="horror" style="display:none">
                        <search>
                            <id>1</id>
                            <name>horror</name>
                            <address>09, west Road</address>
                            <city>London</city>
                            <pcode>se4 7jk</pcode>
                            <contact>020574110832</contact>
                        </search>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" onclick="toggleById('nice'); return true;" onMouseOver="this.style.cursor='hand'" value="nice"></td>
                <td>
                    <div id="nice" style="display:none">
                        <search>
                            <id>2</id>
                            <name>nice</name>
                            <address>05, East Road</address>
                            <city>London</city>
                            <pcode>po4 3df</pcode>
                            <contact>none</contact>
                        </search>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Try it out in a browser and you will experience the expand/collapse behavior.

Comment: Thnx for your reply. But when I click on the name it should expand the result. Not to link another file.

Comment: Kabelash, unless you use the client-side edition of Saxon XSLT can't react to events like a click in the browser. You would need to combine XSLT and Javascript in other cases. To help you we first need to know which XSLT processor you use, where you use it (client or server side).

Comment: @Kabelash if you add the anchors like #horror as id="horror" to some point in your webpage, then the cursor will jump to that point. If you wish to hide and show stuff then you need to do more; specifically add a class to the hidden stuff that toggles hide/show when the link is clicked, aided by some javascript as Martin remarked. Is that what you wish to do?