# Changing the content of a node dynamically in XSL with jQuery or Javascript

Tags: jquery, xml, xslt

I have a XML file with differents nodes and in each node (each node has a unique attribute) some information.

In the XSL file I created a table with the names of the nodes, and want to show/hide the full content of this node when I click on the name(or a button in the same line) in a div outside this table. I have been looking but can't find any solution.

```
<table class="tablesorter" cellspacing="1" border="1" id="tablaPeliculas">
<tbody>
  <xsl:for-each select="Filmoteca/Peliculas/Pelicula">
    <xsl:sort order="ascending"/>
       <xsl:variable name="contador"><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></xsl:variable>
       <tr align="left">
          <td>      
    <button class="flip" id="{$contador}">Mostrar</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

See my other post on a similar subject: [unable-to-put-href-links-to-expand-results-in-xml-using-xslt-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964350/unable-to-put-href-links-to-expand-results-in-xml-using-xslt-file/9964842#9964842) for ideas.

Things to do are: javascript for expand/collapse div elements with id and style attributes.